# Kali Linux Live CD - Where is boot menu?

Tags: linux, boot, installation, kali-linux

I have downloaded the torrent of the latest Kali Linux build. I have burnt the Disk Image to a DVD+R DL Disk, put it in my CD/DVD drive, and ran setup.exe. But when I boot my computer selecting "Debian GNU/Linux", I see no option for "Kali Live". In fact, all I'm offered is the option to continue with the install process. So where is the menu offering choices such as 'Install', 'Graphical Install', 'Start Kali Live' et cetra?

Comment: I haven't used Kali, but it isn't clear from your question whether you had an existing Debian installation or the Debian option you're seeing is Kali (it's a Debian derivative).  If you completed the installation, that Debian option may be it.  The menu described in your last sentence is part of the start menu after you boot from the LiveDVD.  You get to that by selecting the DVD drive as the boot device in the BIOS options.  Basically, you choose whether to run the installed system or a live session (the installed one is no longer a live session).

Comment: @fixer1234 I've used Debian and many other Linux OSes before, but not on the PC where I'm trying to install Kali.

Comment: Then it sounds like the Debian selection is your Kali installation.  Once it's installed, the installed version does not have the menu items you see in a session booting the LiveDVD.  If you need to access those, just boot the LiveDVD again.  That doesn't change.